# Close JFrame after certain time

Tags: java, swing, timer, jframe

So I'm making a game with 3 difficulties:

- Beginner
- Intermediate
- Expert

In the Expert level I want to close the `JFrame` after 60 seconds, either clicking a button to start or *any* other way, doesn't need to be fancy. I've tried many ways but I keep ***not*** getting what I want.

This is my code:

```
package battleship;
import static battleship.Countdown.interval;
import static battleship.Countdown.timer;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;


public class Test {
static int interval;
static Timer timer;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Input seconds => : ");
    String secs = sc.nextLine();
    int delay = 1000;
    int period = 1000;
    timer = new Timer();
    interval = Integer.parseInt(secs);
    System.out.println(secs);
       timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        public void run() {
            System.out.println(setInterval());

        }
    }, delay, period);
}

    private void setIcon1() {
        setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("ramboo.png")));
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                setInterval();
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("BATALLA NAVAL - NIVEL PRINCIPIANTE" );
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(900, 700));

                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    void setVisible(boolean b) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    private void setIconImage(Image image) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

  public TestPane() {

            try {
           for (int i=0; i<=1; i++){
                add(crearespacios());
           }
           for (int i=0; i<=1; i++){
  add(crearbombas());
           }

                //agregar frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


            } 

            catch (IOException exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        protected JToggleButton crearbombas() throws IOException {

            JToggleButton btn = new JToggleButton();
            btn.setModel(new StickyModel());
            btn.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("botondefault.png"))));
            btn.setSelectedIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("bombaa.png"))));
            return btn;

        }

        protected JToggleButton crearespacios() throws IOException {

            JToggleButton btn = new JToggleButton();
            btn.setModel(new StickyModel());
            btn.setBounds(5, 5, 50, 50);
            btn.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("botondefault.png"))));
            btn.setSelectedIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("botondefault.png"))));
            return btn;

        }

        protected JButton Instructions() throws IOException {

            JButton btnX = new JButton();
            btnX.setModel(new StickyModel());
            btnX.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("rambofinal.png"))));
            btnX.setSelectedIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("rambofinal.png"))));
            return btnX;

        }

        protected JTextField Instrucciones() throws IOException {

            JTextField jtxt = new JTextField();
            JTextField jtxt2 = new JTextField();
            jtxt.setText("Existen 18 espacios, 5 barcos ocupan 6 de ellos.");
            jtxt2.setText("Tenes 16 clicks.");
            return jtxt;
        }



    }



private static final int setInterval() {
    if (interval == 1)
        timer.cancel();

    return --interval;

}


    public class StickyModel extends JToggleButton.ToggleButtonModel {

        public void reset() {
            super.setSelected(false);
        }

        @Override
        public void setSelected(boolean b) {
            if (!isSelected()) {
                super.setSelected(b);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Tried using `System.exit(0)` and `System.runfinalization;` here but it only showed me the "Console output(?)" and not also the Frame

Without timer:

```
package battleship;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();

    }

    private void setIcon1() {
        setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("ramboo.png")));
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("BATALLA NAVAL - NIVEL PRINCIPIANTE" );
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(900, 700));

                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    void setVisible(boolean b) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    private void setIconImage(Image image) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

  public TestPane() {

            try {
           for (int i=0; i<=1; i++){
                add(crearespacios());
           }
           for (int i=0; i<=1; i++){
  add(crearbombas());
           }

                //agregar frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


            } 

            catch (IOException exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        protected JToggleButton crearbombas() throws IOException {

            JToggleButton btn = new JToggleButton();
            btn.setModel(new StickyModel());
            btn.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("botondefault.png"))));
            btn.setSelectedIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("bombaa.png"))));
            return btn;

        }

        protected JToggleButton crearespacios() throws IOException {

            JToggleButton btn = new JToggleButton();
            btn.setModel(new StickyModel());
            btn.setBounds(5, 5, 50, 50);
            btn.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("botondefault.png"))));
            btn.setSelectedIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("botondefault.png"))));
            return btn;

        }

        protected JButton Instructions() throws IOException {

            JButton btnX = new JButton();
            btnX.setModel(new StickyModel());
            btnX.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("rambofinal.png"))));
            btnX.setSelectedIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("rambofinal.png"))));
            return btnX;

        }

        protected JTextField Instrucciones() throws IOException {

            JTextField jtxt = new JTextField();
            JTextField jtxt2 = new JTextField();
            jtxt.setText("Existen 18 espacios, 5 barcos ocupan 6 de ellos.");
            jtxt2.setText("Tenes 16 clicks.");
            return jtxt;
        }



    }

    public class StickyModel extends JToggleButton.ToggleButtonModel {

        public void reset() {
            super.setSelected(false);
        }

        @Override
        public void setSelected(boolean b) {
            if (!isSelected()) {
                super.setSelected(b);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

BTW... the game is battleship and I have a custom button created in that code, that's why I need the timer in the same Frame.java as the buttons.

Comment: 1) Post code here, not at an external link that some will not be able to follow, and most won't bother following. 2) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).  Minimal code would not have cruft like `setIcon1()`.. 3) *"the game is battleship and I have a custom button created in that code, that's why I need the timer in the same Frame.java as the buttons."* I was about to edit that sentence until I realized I completely did not understand it. ..

Comment: .. custom buttons can be created on the fly within a class, or as a separate `.java` file.  A `Timer` might also be accessible to a frame whether or not it is the same class/source file.  This really comes to to Object Oriented Programming (specifically, references between objects).

Comment: 1) working with a friend on this so I keep using that site as I update my code... sorry

3) You basically just helped me finish my game with this. I was having a hard time cause I didn't know how to use objects from different files in another code/jframe/file. Now I can use the Design View and just set the model of the jToggleButton and control it without having to code much.

Comment: *"You basically just helped me finish my game with this."*  Congratulations!  Glad you got it sorted.  :)  Now you can either 1) delete the question or (better) 2) write up an answer.